# How to run Powershell commands in Django Web App in Production. (Azure Web Apps)

Tags: django, powershell, azure-webapps

i have a Django App that i want to deploy to Azure Web Apps. Some functions require interaction with Windows Powershell. Im using subprocess.Popen to execute specific commands directly in powershell and catch the output. Locally this is running fine but i am afraid these funtions will no longer work when deploying to Azure. Please see below a sample function. And yes i am planning to validate and sanitize inputs. Anybody had a comparable scenario and can help me out?

```
def assign_mailbox_permission(tenant, user, mail_group):
    secret = get_secret(keeper_uids[tenant]['M365 Zentrale API Administrator'])
    username = secret['login']
    password = secret['password']
    if tenant == "einsnulleins Schloß Holte-Stukenbrock":
        mail_group = mail_group.replace("standort.", "")
    else: 
        mail_group = mail_group.replace("standort", tenant.replace("ä", "ae").replace("ü", "ue").replace("ö", "oe").replace("ß", "ss").lower())
    powershell_command = f'$UserCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "{username}", (ConvertTo-SecureString "{password}" -AsPlainText -Force); Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName "{username}" -Credential $UserCredential; Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "{mail_group}" -User "{user}" -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All '
    command_args = ["powershell.exe", "-Command", powershell_command]
    mailbox_error = "Ex6F9304"
    not_found_error = "Ex9BC9DD"
    counter = 0
    while True:
        process = subprocess.Popen(command_args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        stdout, stderr= process.communicate()
        error = stderr.decode('utf-8', errors='replace')
        counter += 1
        if error == '':
            result = {
                'update': f'Benutzer Berechtigungen für {mail_group} erteilt',
                'success': True
            }
            return result
        if mailbox_error in error:
            result = {
                'update': f'Postfach {mail_group} existiert nicht in diesem Tenant, überspringe Postfach...',
                'success': False
            }
            return result
        elif counter == 20:
            result = {
                'update': f'Maximale Anzahl an Versuchen Benutzer zu {mail_group} hinzuzufügen erreicht, überspringe Postfach',
                'success': False
            }
            return result
        elif not_found_error in error:
            continue
        else:
            result = {
                'update': f'Fehler beim Hinzufügen zu {mail_group}. Fehler: {error}',
                'success': False
            }
            return result
```

I did a lot of research but found nothing that fits my case, ChatGPT also cant really help.